# uvc_camera, load calibration file

Tags: ros, calibration, camera-calibration, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I'm relatively new in the ros community.. so at the moment I am playing around with ros and image processing to get into it..

the problem I get is the following: the uvc_cam node seems to be unable to load my calibration file.. so image_proc reports: [ERROR] [1303148787.949737953]: Rectified topic '/mono/image_rect_color' requested but camera publishing '/mono/camera_info' is uncalibrated

any ideas? here an extract out of my launch file:

```
  <node ns="mono" name="camera_node" pkg="uvc_camera" type="camera_node" output="screen" >
    <param name="device"  value="/dev/video0" />
    <param name="fps" value="30" />
    <param name="width" value="640" />
    <param name="height" value="480" />
    <param name="camera_info_url" type="string" value="file:///home/blub/ros/camtesting/calibration_camera.yaml" />
  </node>

  <node name="image_view_raw" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <remap from="image" to="/mono/image_raw"/>
    <param name="autosize" value="true" />
  </node>

  <node ns="mono" name="proc" pkg="image_proc" type="image_proc" output="screen" >
  </node>

  <node name="mono_view" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" output="screen" >
    <remap from="image"  to="mono/image_rect_color" />
  </node>
```

another strange thing is, that the calibration script did't save the calibration to the URL above but into the tmp folder..

Thanks for you Help,
Ulli

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9758/uvc_camera,-load-calibration-file/) by [Ulli](https://answers.ros.org/users/415/ulli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe this was a bug that caused trouble whenever the name="..." attribute was specified for a node. It should be fixed in camera_umd version 0.1.2 (debs are available).

---

Originally posted by [Ken](https://answers.ros.org/users/13/ken/) with karma: 438 on 2011-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0